# Page jumps on scroll to sticky footer on mobile only

Tags: css, reactjs, mobile, sass

for some reason my website continues to jump at the end of the page and the footer is not visible - however only on mobile. I have no clue what I could do differently. Maybe someone has an advice for me? I build my app using React. I already added extra margins to the bottoms of the body, the root, the div before to test it but nothing works!

Thanks a lot in advance!

code on github: https://github.com/seabysalt/myWebsite
website: www.sarah-alt.com

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the issue you're facing.

Comment: you mean the behaviour on homepage when it is loaded in mobile it jump past the first hero section to that maps section? i see footer is visible if we scroll down.

Comment: No, the problem is that when on the mobile device (not on mobile screen in my browser on the laptop), I cannot see the footer and if I scroll all the way down to the bottom of the page it starts to jump up and down really fast (as if it is struck my lightning), so you won't see anything on a screenshot